# Is there a way to trim out observations with a known format?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I am working with a database with 40+ variables. Each case has a unique identifier for its property. Some of these identifiers have been inputted into the address variable.

The identifiers can only take the following formats:

```
NA123456 - First letter constant - N, 1 Letter A-K, Numbers 1-9
SA123456 - First 2 letters constant - SA, 6 Numbers 0-9
MABC1234 - First letter constant - M, 3 Letters A-Z, 4 Numbers 0-9
QABC1234 - First letter constant - Q, 3 Letters A-Z, 4 Numbers 0-9
WABC1234 - First letter constant - W, 3 Letters A-Z, 4 Numbers 1-9
TABC1234 - First letter constant - T, 3 Letters A-Z, 4 Numbers 1-9
3ABCD123 - First number constant - 3, 3 Letters A-Z, 3 Numbers 1-9
```

I am unsure how to trim out the unique identifiers from the address text they are in without creating a lookup table and using left_join. The lookup table would need to be updated constantly making it very cumbersome.

I haven't been able to find an example of this sort of thing yet. I may have missed something though.

My data looks like this:

```
Property                        Address               `Aa reference`
   <chr>                           <chr>                 <lgl>         
 1 PIC: 3WABG086                   260 SPRINGHURST ROAD  NA            
 2 PIC: 35PSR217                   1350 RIVER ROAD       NA            
 3 PIC# NH244157                   1038 QUONDONG ROAD    NA            
 4 PIC: 3GMUF425                   70 DIGBY ROAD         NA            
 5 PIC# 3GMUF425                   70 DIGBY ROAD         NA            
 6 PIC QTIWW0626                   REMOLEA               NA            
 7 PIC#EBWSE235                    BOX 191               NA            
 8 PIC #3WLKM019                   198 MONTGOMERY ROAD   NA            
 9 PIC # 3BWMM021                  149 ANDERSONS ROAD    NA            
10 PIC: 3WCGN034                   WERRIBEE              NA            
11 GARANGULA PIC: NH630488         PO BOX 84             NA            
12 GARANGULA PIC: NH630488         PO BOX 84             NA            
13 PIC: 3GMTL320                   2980 GLENELG HIGHWAY  NA            
14 GREENSLOPES PIC: MJKE0261       914 WEST KENTISH ROAD NA            
15 PIC: WFZB3246                   859 PFEIFFER ROAD     NA            
16 PIC: WFAY3549                   34605 ALBANY HIGHWAY  NA            
17 PIC: 3CEXK044                   2244 LAVERS HILL ROAD NA            
18 PIC: QGWW0462                   ELDERFIELD            NA            
19 PIC: 3WCGN034                   WERRIBEE              NA            
20 KAYA DORPER & WHITE DORPER STUD PIC: WABN0262         NA            
21 SPOTTSWOOD                      PIC QKDR0078          NA            
22 COOMBOONA HOLSTEINS             PIC 3SPSR217          NA            
23 ROSEVALE                        PIC: QKEV0169         NA            
24 NA                              PIC 3EGON009          NA            
25 NA                              PIC WFKPO316          NA            
26 IVADENE                         PIC 3WANP0T1          NA            
27 NA                              PIC ND225813          NA            
28 HEAVENLY VALLEY FARMS           PIC #NF538645         NA            
29 C/- CED WISE AB CENTRE          PIC: QCST0158         NA            
30 GARANGULA                       PIC # NH630488        NA
```

The clean data would end up with the unique identifers in the `aa reference` column and wouldn't overwrite the observations that have the data in the correct variable with NA.

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please edit your question by adding output of `dput(yourData[1:30, ])`.

Comment: Are there fixed numbers of letters or numbers in the IDs? E.g. is Q always followed by 3 letters, 4 numbers if it's a valid ID? If so that would make checking for IDs easier.

Comment: You say numbers 1-9.. A lot of rows contain the nu,ber 0. Should they be excluded? Also: is the length of the search-string fixed?

Comment: @Marius, Yes that's correct I have updated the question.

Comment: @Wimpel, I have updated the question to include the 0-9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked in the end:

```
vec <- c( "N[A-K]{1}[0-9]+", 
          "SA[0-9]+",
          "M[A-Z]+[0-9]+",
          "Q[A-Z]+[0-9]+",
          "W[A-Z]+[0-9]+",
          "T[A-Z]+[0-9]+",
          "3[A-Z]+[0-9]+" )

#paste patterns together to one large regex-OR-pattern
pattern <- paste( vec, collapse = "|" )

df <- df %>%
  mutate(`id1` = str_extract_all(`Property`, vec),
         `id2` = str_extract_all(`Address`, vec),
         `id1` = na_if(`Pic1`, "character(0)"),
         `id2` = na_if(`Pic2`, "character(0)")
  ) %>% 
  unite(id3, id1, id2, remove = TRUE, sep = " ") %>% 
  mutate(`id3` = str_extract_all(id3, vec),
         `id3` = na_if(`id3`, "character(0)"))
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible answer, using regex-patterns and `stringr::str_extract_all()`

I assumed your numbers should be 0-9, and not 1-9. If not, change all `[0-9]` to `[1-9]`.
Also, if you are looking for a specific number of (say: n) repetetitions of letters/numbers, change the `+` to `{n}`, like in the first pattern  in `vec`.

```
library( data.table )
library( stringr )

# NA123456 - First letter constant - N, Letter A-K, Numbers 1-9
# SA123456 - First 2 letters constant - SA, Numbers 1-9
# MABC1234 - First letter constant - M, Letters A-Z, Numbers 1-9
# QABC1234 - First letter constant - Q, Letters A-Z, Numbers 1-9
# WABC1234 - First letter constant - W, Letters A-Z, Numbers 1-9
# TABC1234 - First letter constant - T, Letters A-Z, Numbers 1-9
# 3ABCD123 - First number constant - 3, Letters A-Z, Numbers 1-9

#create a vector with all regex-patterns
#I assumed 1-9 should be 0-9 ??             <-- !!
vec <- c( "N[A-K]{1}[0-9]+", 
          "SA[0-9]+",
          "M[A-Z]+[0-9]+",
          "Q[A-Z]+[0-9]+",
          "W[A-Z]+[0-9]+",
          "T[A-Z]+[0-9]+",
          "3[A-Z]+[0-9]+" )
#paste patterns together to one large regex-OR-pattern
pattern <- paste( vec, collapse = "|" )
#extract all patterns from the column 'Property', and put (as vector) in Aa-reference
#extract all patterns from the column 'Property', and put (as vector) in Aa-reference
DT[, Aa_reference := stringr::str_extract_all( Address, pattern )]
```

**output**

```
#                           Property               Address Aa_reference
# 1:                   PIC: 3WABG086  260 SPRINGHURST ROAD             
# 2:                   PIC: 35PSR217       1350 RIVER ROAD             
# 3:                   PIC# NH244157    1038 QUONDONG ROAD             
# 4:                   PIC: 3GMUF425         70 DIGBY ROAD             
# 5:                   PIC# 3GMUF425         70 DIGBY ROAD             
# 6:                   PIC QTIWW0626               REMOLEA             
# 7:                    PIC#EBWSE235               BOX 191             
# 8:                   PIC #3WLKM019   198 MONTGOMERY ROAD             
# 9:                  PIC # 3BWMM021    149 ANDERSONS ROAD             
# 10:                   PIC: 3WCGN034              WERRIBEE             
# 11:         GARANGULA PIC: NH630488             PO BOX 84             
# 12:         GARANGULA PIC: NH630488             PO BOX 84             
# 13:                   PIC: 3GMTL320  2980 GLENELG HIGHWAY             
# 14:       GREENSLOPES PIC: MJKE0261 914 WEST KENTISH ROAD             
# 15:                   PIC: WFZB3246     859 PFEIFFER ROAD             
# 16:                   PIC: WFAY3549  34605 ALBANY HIGHWAY             
# 17:                   PIC: 3CEXK044 2244 LAVERS HILL ROAD             
# 18:                   PIC: QGWW0462            ELDERFIELD             
# 19:                   PIC: 3WCGN034              WERRIBEE             
# 20: KAYA DORPER & WHITE DORPER STUD         PIC: WABN0262     WABN0262
# 21:                      SPOTTSWOOD          PIC QKDR0078     QKDR0078
# 22:             COOMBOONA HOLSTEINS          PIC 3SPSR217     3SPSR217
# 23:                        ROSEVALE         PIC: QKEV0169     QKEV0169
# 24:                            <NA>          PIC 3EGON009     3EGON009
# 25:                            <NA>          PIC WFKPO316     WFKPO316
# 26:                         IVADENE          PIC 3WANP0T1       3WANP0
# 27:                            <NA>          PIC ND225813     ND225813
# 28:           HEAVENLY VALLEY FARMS         PIC #NF538645     NF538645
# 29:          C/- CED WISE AB CENTRE         PIC: QCST0158     QCST0158
# 30:                       GARANGULA        PIC # NH630488     NH630488
#                            Property               Address Aa_reference
```

**sample data used**

```
DT <- fread('
Property |                       Address |              Aa_reference
PIC: 3WABG086|                   260 SPRINGHURST ROAD|  NA            
PIC: 35PSR217|                   1350 RIVER ROAD      | NA            
PIC# NH244157|                   1038 QUONDONG ROAD    |NA            
PIC: 3GMUF425|                   70 DIGBY ROAD|         NA            
PIC# 3GMUF425|                   70 DIGBY ROAD |        NA            
PIC QTIWW0626 |                  REMOLEA        |       NA            
PIC#EBWSE235   |                 BOX 191         |      NA            
PIC #3WLKM019   |                198 MONTGOMERY ROAD|   NA            
PIC # 3BWMM021   |               149 ANDERSONS ROAD  |  NA            
PIC: 3WCGN034     |              WERRIBEE             | NA            
GARANGULA PIC: NH630488|         PO BOX 84             |NA            
GARANGULA PIC: NH630488 |        PO BOX 84|             NA            
PIC: 3GMTL320|                   2980 GLENELG HIGHWAY|  NA            
GREENSLOPES PIC: MJKE0261|       914 WEST KENTISH ROAD| NA            
PIC: WFZB3246           |        859 PFEIFFER ROAD|     NA            
PIC: WFAY3549|                   34605 ALBANY HIGHWAY|  NA            
PIC: 3CEXK044 |                  2244 LAVERS HILL ROAD| NA            
PIC: QGWW0462  |                 ELDERFIELD|            NA            
PIC: 3WCGN034   |                WERRIBEE|              NA            
KAYA DORPER & WHITE DORPER STUD| PIC: WABN0262|         NA            
SPOTTSWOOD|                      PIC QKDR0078  |        NA            
COOMBOONA HOLSTEINS|             PIC 3SPSR217   |       NA            
ROSEVALE            |            PIC: QKEV0169   |      NA            
NA|                              PIC 3EGON009     |     NA            
NA |                             PIC WFKPO316      |    NA            
IVADENE|                         PIC 3WANP0T1       |   NA            
NA      |                        PIC ND225813        |  NA            
HEAVENLY VALLEY FARMS|           PIC #NF538645        | NA            
C/- CED WISE AB CENTRE|          PIC: QCST0158         |NA            
GARANGULA|                       PIC # NH630488        |NA
', sep = "|")
```

Comment: I think the question asks for the IDs to be extracted from the Address column (since they shouldn't really be there, this seems like part of the process of cleaning the data).

Comment: @Wimpel thank you for your help so far. If I have my data frame as a tibble currently do I have to convert it to a `data.table` or can I keep it as a `tibble` and alter the code? Thank you.

Comment: key is the creation of a patterns, and then use the `str_extract_all()`-function. You cad do this on a data.table (like in my example), but also in any other way that you usually create new columns with.

Comment: @Wimpel, I get a lot of `character(0)` outputs in the new column. These overide the original data in the the `Aa reference` when I try to combine the 3 new columns together. Can I do a combine by hierachy? or would I be best off to delete the `character(0)` prior to attempting a `unite` ?